# YUI compressor not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, yui-compressor

I tried compressing a JavaScript file of mine using YUI compressor, but somehow it did not do what was expected.

The JavaScript file is [here](http://github.com/jrharshath/agilance/raw/master/js/jswaf.js).

The compressed output looked like this:

```
    !window.$j&&(function($){$.jswaf={};$j=$.jswaf;var resources={},modules={},depends={},events={},eventfired={},modulepath={},themepath={}; [...]
```

and so on.

What I expected was that variables like "resources", "modules", "depends" etc would be reduced to small 1, 2 or 3 letter identifiers.

Is this what is supposed to happen? Or is something wrong with my source file?

BTW:

1. The compressor puked this output (I used *-v* option):

   > [WARNING] Try to use a single 'var'
   >   statement per scope.
   >   ={},themepath={}; ---> var  <--- _nullf=function(){};var WAIT_TIME_RECHECK_FETCHED
   >
   > [WARNING] Try to use a single 'var'
   >   statement per scope. var
   >   _nullf=function(){}; ---> var  <--- WAIT_TIME_RECHECK_FETCHED=300;var
   >   WAIT_TIME_LOAD_CALLBACK=20;var
   >
   > [WARNING] Try to use a single 'var'
   >   statement per scope. ){};var
   >   WAIT_TIME_RECHECK_FETCHED=300; --->
   >   var  <---
   >   WAIT_TIME_LOAD_CALLBACK=20;var
   >   WAIT_TIME_UNLOAD_CALLBACK=20;var
   >
   > [WARNING] Try to use a single 'var'
   >   statement per scope.
   >   WAIT_TIME_RECHECK_FETCHED=300;var
   >   WAIT_TIME_LOAD_CALLBACK=20; ---> var 
   >   <--- WAIT_TIME_UNLOAD_CALLBACK=20;var
   >   WAIT_TIME_EVENT_FIRE=20;var
   >
   > [WARNING] Try to use a single 'var'
   >   statement per scope.
   >   WAIT_TIME_LOAD_CALLBACK=20;var
   >   WAIT_TIME_UNLOAD_CALLBACK=20; ---> var
   >   <--- WAIT_TIME_EVENT_FIRE=20;var
   >   WAIT_TIME_ADD_REPO_CALLBACK=20;$j
   >
   > [WARNING] Try to use a single 'var'
   >   statement per scope.
   >   WAIT_TIME_UNLOAD_CALLBACK=20;var
   >   WAIT_TIME_EVENT_FIRE=20; ---> var 
   >   <---
   >   WAIT_TIME_ADD_REPO_CALLBACK=20;$j.resources=resources;
   >
   > [WARNING] Try to use a single 'var'
   >   statement per scope. ;}var
   >   modpath=path+"modules/module-list.js";
   >   ---> var  <--- thpath=path+"themes/theme-list.js";functionfinish(val
   >
   > [WARNING] Try to use a single 'var'
   >   statement per scope.
   >   +module+"/";}}for( ---> var  <--- theme in thlist){theme=thlist[theme
   >
   > [WARNING] Try to use a single 'var'
   >   statement per scope.
   >   false){returnfalse;}for( ---> var 
   >   <--- res in obj.prod){if(resources
   >
   > [WARNING] Try to use a single 'var'
   >   statement per scope. (var req in
   >   module.req){ ---> var  <---
   >   found=false;var
   >   dependents=depends[resources
   >
   > [WARNING] Try to use a single 'var'
   >   statement per scope. .req){var
   >   found=false; ---> var  <---
   >   dependents=depends[resources[req].id
   >
   > [WARNING] Try to use a single 'var'
   >   statement per scope. [req].id];for(
   >   ---> var  <--- moduleIdIndex in dependents){if(moduleIdIndex==module
   >
   > [WARNING] Try to use a single 'var'
   >   statement per scope. ,arg3){var id="";
   >   ---> var  <--- conf={};var callback=_nullf;
   >
   > [WARNING] Try to use a single 'var'
   >   statement per scope.
   >   ="";var conf={}; ---> var  <--- callback=_nullf;if(typeofarg1=="string"
   >
   > [WARNING] Try to use a single 'var'
   >   statement per scope.
   >   return;}path=path+"module.js"; --->
   >   var  <---
   >   done=false;functionfetchDoneCallback(){done
   >
   > [WARNING] Try to use a single 'var'
   >   statement per scope. {return;}var
   >   callback=null; ---> var  <---
   >   recursive=null;if(typeofarg1=="function"
   >
   > [WARNING] Try to use a single 'var'
   >   statement per scope. [dep];}}}for(
   >   ---> var  <--- prod in modules[modId].prod){
   >
   > [WARNING] Try to use a single 'var'
   >   statement per scope.
   >   (true);return;}else{ ---> var  <---
   >   dependents=depends[moduleId];for(var
   >
   > [WARNING] Try to use a single 'var'
   >   statement per scope.
   >   dependents=depends[moduleId];for( --->
   >   var  <--- index in
   >   dependents){$.jswaf.unloadModule
   >
   > [WARNING] Using 'eval' is not
   >   recommended. Moreover, using 'eval'
   >   reduces the level of compression!
   >   ,function(data){var conf= ---> eval
   >   <--- (data);var css=conf.css
   >
   > [WARNING] Try to use a single 'var'
   >   statement per scope. {var
   >   conf=eval(data); ---> var  <---
   >   css=conf.css;for(i in
   >
   > [WARNING] Found an undeclared symbol:
   >   $j ){$.jswaf={}; ---> $j <---
   >   =$.jswaf;var resources={}
   >
   > [WARNING] Found an undeclared symbol:
   >   ind
   >   evtListeners=getListeners(evt);for(
   >   ---> ind <---  in evtListeners){setTimeout(evtListeners[ind]
   >
   > [WARNING] Found an undeclared symbol:
   >   i WAIT_TIME_EVENT_FIRE);}}else{for(
   >   ---> i <--- =eventfired[evt];i>0;
   >
   > [WARNING] Found an undeclared symbol:
   >   mod ;delete depends[modId];for( --->
   >   mod <---  in depends){var
   >   deps=depends[mod
   >
   > [WARNING] Found an undeclared symbol:
   >   dep deps=depends[mod];for( ---> dep
   >   <---  in deps){if(dep==modId)
2. Do I need to install Rhino separately for YUI compressor to work? Or is it packaged along with YUI compressor?

Thanks,
jrh

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me as if it would be happier if you added declarations for all of your Javascript variables.

Comment: The only problem with this is that many plugins and libraries that you download from open source projects do not declare the variables ;(